# as3 If i use fluid movements I can't hitTest Objects?

Tags: actionscript-3

I used the movement where you set up variables for movement in keydown.

You set them to true if key is down.

```
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            bLeft = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            bRight = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            bUp = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
        {
            bDown = true;
        }
```

And on key up you set them to false, and on enterframe you set them to move if the variables are true.

However if I do it this way instead of the way where you set player movement at the key down, instead of using variables.

The fluid way wouldn't work when I use hitTestObject to stop moving. If I touch the object, I just stop there and stay. I can't move back.

I use player.vy -= speed, player.vx -= speed;

However if I used the original, way hitTestObject would work fine.

Hit Test for the player.

It's inside the enterframe.

```
if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(wall0))
        {
            player.y -= vy;
        }
```

Comment: Show where and how you use hitTest.

Comment: I use hitTest in the enterframe. I put code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're continuing to trigger hittest so you'd need to build in a condition that ignores the hittest IF you're new direction is away from the direction you were travelling when triggering hittest.

I would suggest something like (psuedo):
* on hittest then set 'hitDirection' to currentDirection and reset downs
* onEnterFrame: if (hitTest && direction == opposite of hitDirection) then move

Comment: @Crook did this solve your issue or are you still having problems?